# Fixed table header on window scroll

Tags: angular, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple Bootstrap table with a lot of rows.
Is there a way to make the table header be fixed when scrolling the window, but have the width of each column header to equal the width of the row with the most text.
Because when setting table header position to fixed, then the header doesn't change its width based off the content.
In other words set width of each column dependent on widest value (be that title in the header or value in a cell) in the column.
Is there a way to put such calculations on the header column width ?
I cant think of any other way to do this.
I am using angular.

Here's a jsfiddle of what I've tried when setting position of header row to fixed : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adsrr8ss/1/)
As you can see now the columns don't align with the appropriate columns in the body.
I need them to be aligned, but without setting a fixed width for every column, since I do not know how long the data I'm getting will be.

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 tableDiv"  >
 <table class="table table-striped" >
  <thead class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
      <th>Column6</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td > FIRST</td>
      <td >asdasdfasf</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td > asdf</td>
      <td >asdfa</td>
      <td >fsdf</td>
      <td>sdfsfd</td>
      <td>sdfs</td>
      <td>fsdfsdf</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
<div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.table-bordered tr {
  position: fixed;
   z-index:1;
  top: 50px;
  background: #fff;
 }
```

Comment: This question is very broad, in the sense that it depends on a lot of factors what would, and what wouldn't work. It would be more helpful to post some code or a jsfiddle what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you. 
I did add the code and additional explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the performance and you can live without borders in the header (because the borders will not get the `CSS` transform), there is a solution using `CSS3` transforms. The technique is to take the scroll of the window and apply a transform to the header with the same value. In this way, the header is not fixed and it maintains its original widths:

```
let header = document.querySelector(".table-bordered");
let body = document.body;

function setTranslate (element, value) {
    let style = `translateY(${value}px)`;
    element.style.oTransform = style;
    element.style.MozTransform = style;
    element.style.WebkitTransform = style;
    element.style.transform = style;
}

window.onscroll = () => {
    setTranslate(header, window.scrollY);
};
```

[jsFiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/um1jrrrm/)

The bad part about this solution is that you need to update the styles of the header in every scroll event, so, the performance will not be well enough. Another solution is to build two different tables, one for the header and another for the body and a generic function that set the widths of the header taking into account the widths of the body. In this way, you can set the `position` property of the table in `fixed` and you could call this function in every resize of the window or in every moment that you need to refresh the sizes of the table. Take a look at the next snippet:

```js
let header = document.querySelector(".table-header");
let body = document.querySelector(".table-body");
let htds = header.querySelectorAll("th");
let btds = body.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:first-child td");

function fixHeaderWidths() {
  header.style.width = `${body.offsetWidth}px`;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(htds, (td, index) => {
    td.style.width = `${btds[index].offsetWidth}px`;
  });
  body.style.top = "";
  let top = (header.getBoundingClientRect()).bottom - (btds[0].getBoundingClientRect()).top;
  body.style.top = `${top}px`;
}

fixHeaderWidths();

window.onresize = fixHeaderWidths;
```

```css
.table-header {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  table-layout: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.table-body {
  position: relative;
}

.table-body thead {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tableDiv {
  margin-top: 40px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12 tableDiv">
  <table class="table-header table table-stripedcf table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
        <th>Column6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <table class="table-body table table-stripedcf table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
        <th>Column6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>FIRST</td>
        <td>asda sdfasf</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdf</td>
        <td>asdfa</td>
        <td>fsdf</td>
        <td>sdfsfd</td>
        <td>sdfs</td>
        <td>fsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

> If you don't want to use `jQuery`, don't use the `Bootstrap` script file (I've seen that you have included it in your `jsFiddle`) because it requires `jQuery` to work. But you can use to replace it something like [this](https://github.com/thednp/bootstrap.native).

Comment: Thank you but I shouldn't have the scrolling inside the table body.
The thing that makes it difficult is that on window scroll the table header should stay fixed.
And can't use Jquery as it doesn't blend well with Angular.
That's why I was asking if there is a way to have the actual thead hidden ( the one that gets the width based on the content) 
And a fixed table header whose column width will equal the ones of the hidden header.

Comment: @JenPen lkjk, let me try and I will update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. 
The only thing needed is the width of the fixed header to not be manually set. Because it should change based of the rows of that column.
As it normally does when it's not fixed.
Thank you for trying ! Appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanations. 
But the second example doesn't work well, because when its' the header that has a longer width than the content in its respective rows, then they overlap and don't align well.

Comment: @JenPenlkjk These techniques are to give you an idea of which approach you can follow. If your header has longer texts than your content, in that case, you need to do the opposite: set the width to your body `tds` taking into account the widths of your header `ths`. So, just a simple condition to do one or other approach will be enough.

Comment: @JenPenlkjk, or a better solution, add the same header in the body table but with `visibility` `hidden`, in this way, the width of the body columns will be calculated by the browser ;) Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/pu4q1931/). I am going to update the answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! That's the direction I was looking for to follow. Just trying to understand though :
 ` Array.prototype.forEach.call(htds, (td, index) => {
    td.style.width = `${btds[index].offsetWidth}px`;
  });` What does this line do ?
Is this how you set the width of each td in the header to equal the width of the header column in the hidden thead ?

Comment: Hi, I am glad that it worked for you. Yes, that line is to iterate through the header `ths` `NodeList` object (the `NodeList` `forEach` method is not implemented in all browsers so I've used the `Array.prototype.forEach` method to do it). In each iteration, it sets the same width of the respective element placed inside the first row of the body table.